# Inheritance in Python, init method overrriding

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to understand inheritance in Python. I have 4 different kind of logs that I want to process: cpu, ram, net and disk usage

I decided to implement this with classes, as they're formally the same except for the log file reading and the data type for the data. I have a the following code (log object is a logging object instance of a custom logging class)

```
class LogFile():    
    def __init__(self,log_file):
        self._log_file=log_file
        self.validate_log()

    def validate_log(self):
        try:
            with open(self._log_file) as dummy_log_file:
                pass
        except IOError as e:
               log.log_error(str(e[0])+' '+e[1]+' for log file '+self._log_file)

class Data(LogFile):
    def __init__(self,log_file):
        LogFile.__init__(self, log_file)
        self._data=''

    def get_data(self):
        return self._data

    def set_data(self,data):
        self._data=data

    def validate_data(self):
        if self._data == '':
            log.log_debug("Empty data list")

class DataCPU(Data):    
    def read_log(self):            
        self.validate_log()
        reading and writing to LIST stuff

        return LIST


class DataRAM(Data):
    def read_log(self):            
        self.validate_log()    
        reading and writing to LIST stuff

        return LIST

class DataNET(Data):
```

Now I want my `DataNET` class to be a object of the `Data` Class with some more attributes, in particular a dictionary for every one of the interfaces. How can I override the `__init__()` method to be the same as the `Data.__init__()` but adding `self.dict={}` without copying the Data builder? This is, without explicitly specifing the `DataNet` objects do have a `._data` attribute, but inherited from `Data`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Just do `self.dict={}` after calling `Data.__init__(self, log_file)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call the `Data.__init__()` method from `DataNET.__init__()`, then set `self._data = {}`:

```
class DataNET(Data):
    def __init__(self, logfile):
        Data.__init__(self, logfile)
        self._data = {}
```

Now whatever `Data.__init__()` does to `self` happens first, leaving your `DataNET` initializer to add new attributes or override attributes set by the parent initializer.

In Python 3 classes are already new-style, but if this is Python 2, I'd add `object` as a base class to `LogFile()` to make it new-style too:

```
class LogFile(object):
```

after which you can use [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) to automatically look up the parent `__init__` method to call; this has the advantage that in a more complex cooperative inheritance scheme the right methods are invoked in the right order:

```
class Data(LogFile):
    def __init__(self,log_file):
        super(Data, self).__init__(log_file)
        self._data = ''

class DataNET(Data):
    def __init__(self, logfile):
        super(DataNET, self).__init__(logfile)
        self._data = {}
```

`super()` provides you with bound methods, so you don't need to pass in `self` as an argument to `__init__` in that case. In Python 3, you can omit the arguments to `super()` altogether:

```
class Data(LogFile):
    def __init__(self,log_file):
        super().__init__(log_file)
        self._data = ''

class DataNET(Data):
    def __init__(self, logfile):
        super().__init__(logfile)
        self._data = {}
```

Comment: seems like we meet each other frequently :) +1 for a more elaborated answer while mine provides only necessary changes.

Comment: I apparently spend too much time here. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use new style classes (inherit from object) - change definition of `LogFile` to:

```
class LogFile(object):
```

and **init** method of `Data` to:

```
def __init__(self, log_file):
    super(Data, self).__init__(log_file)
    self._data = ''
```

Then you can define `DataNET` as:

```
class DataNET(Data):
    def __init__(self, log_file):
        super(DataNET, self).__init__(log_file)
        self.dict = {}
```